Can anyone tell me the name of this movie where the woman in it wants to be pregnant and i guess she looks for a sperm donor?
I've seen this movie maybe 4 or 5 years ago but I don't remember a lot of it.
So the woman is maybe in her thirties and I remember she and one of her friends were searching in some sites that were for sperm donors i mean they put their photos in their accounts and wrote information like their ages and their jobs and they were mostly handsome men. 
I also remember the woman when she was about having sex with a man who worked with her I guess, but she changed her mind afterwards and she didn't want to have sex with him and she went out quickly wearing only her underwear and some men were laughing at her.
The movie was made after 2000 i think and the language was english and i guess it was american.

What do you consider "a long time ago"?

Well i mean years ago maybe 4 or 5 years i don't know exactly

Ok, for most people "a long time ago" means 4-5 decades. Please clarify your question by editing it.

Ok, i'm sorry i didn't know that.

Welcome to Movies & TV! We have a minimum standard for ID questions. Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.

Any chance it is
"Just Sex and Nothing Else", a.k.a "Csak szex és más semmi" (2005)?
IMDb:

Dora rejects all men when she discovers that her fiance has been
  living a double life with another women throughout their relationship
  (he was married). But with her biological clock ticking, Dora feels
  the urge to have a baby. She places an ad, searching for sex with no
  strings attached. When she finds that her choices are limited to three
  men: Tamas, Ali, and Peter, Dora realizes that her plan is not as
  simple as she had anticipated.

It is not an American movie, but the basic premise is the same. And early in the movie there is a scene where the main protagonist girl (Dora) and her lawyer lover are about to have sex in his office, but the lawyer's wife arrives unexpectedly, the lawyer quickly locks Dora out to the balcony. She is alone on the balcony and wears only her panties, and there are workers below who are working on the road, they notice the half naked girl on the balcony and laugh at her.
Also, at one point in the movie, the girl visits a sperm bank clinic where she looks for a sperm donor. 
Here is a trailer (dubbed in its original Hungarian):



You can watch the complete movie here (dubbed in its original Hungarian):



Early in the movie, at 0:07:00 starts the scene where the girl is on the balcony half naked and the road workers, after noticing her, start laughing at her. The sperm bank/clinic scene starts at 0:23:00.
Girl half naked on the balcony, with the neighbor guy teasing her:

Road workers below teasing her and laughing at her:

Doctor at the sperm bank/clinic explaining the procedure to the girl:

Maybe you saw an English dubbed version of this movie? 

Thanks casspir i really appreciate that you explained this to me, but although it looks so much like the movie i watched still it is not it :( i'm sure the movie language was American, and the girl is not in a balcony, the workers see her when she runs to her car wearing only her panties and her bra.
